# Does it matter what the salt is?

Tags: php, crypt, blowfish

I want to use a `blowfish` `crypt()` in `php` but I am scared that i will use a wrong salt. Is there something like a wrong salt? And is a salt that is for instance `2020352352` worse than salt that is `lkfjaslj5l3k`? I know you should put something random in it and I am planning on doing that.

Comment: The salt has to be cryptographically secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why reinvent the wheel?**

> `Password_hash()` uses a strong hash, generates a strong salt, and
>   applies proper rounds automatically. `password_hash()` is a simple
>   `crypt()` wrapper and compatible with existing password hashes. Use of
>   `password_hash()` is encouraged. *Source:* [Crypt - PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

If you want to use *blowfish:*

> **PASSWORD_BCRYPT** - Use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm to create the hash.

The salt that you can pass through the `(array) $options` argument is optional, if omitted `password_hash()` will automatically create a salt. You can count on `password_hash()` coming up with a good enough salt, i.e. secure.